# JasperReport FileNotFound exception, I'm missing something?

Tags: java, file, io, jasper-reports

Well I'm trying to create a simple report based on Jasper samples jrxml.

The JRXML file is under resources folder, as maven project, something like

```
main/
    java/
    resources/FirstJasper.jrxml
    web/
```

I wrote so far this,
 I also tried `File file = new File("FistJasper.jrxml");`

```
 public static void initReport() {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:\\Development\\Workspace\\Joao's Workspace\\Studium\\src\\main\\resources\\FistJasper.jrxml");
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Map params = new HashMap<>();
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
            LOGGER.warn("JASPER: ", jasperReport.getName());

            LOGGER.warn("JASPER: ", inputStream.read());



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

I'm getting a FileNotFound exception on InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
Am I missing some steps on reading the file or there is other way I can pass the correct path to Jasper?

Comment: You need to use `getResourceAsStream` here

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov like this? `InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("FistJasper.jrxml");`

Comment: Yeah, something like that. It will load file from classpath

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov it's now returning NullPointerException on InputStream

Comment: You have a typo `FistJasper` instead of first

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I corrected and still NullPointer, then I tried this, `InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/FirstJasper.jrxml");` the NullPointer is gone! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use absolute paths, instead, create a classpath folder and put your jrxml inside of it, like this.

[classpath folder for jrxml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOYqF.png)

I got something like this, note that it is very important to use YourClassName.class.getResource method so you can properly load the resource once you create the executable jar file.

```
JasperReport jaspe=(JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(GuiPrincipal.class.getResource("/reportes/reporteInventario.jasper"));
                    JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jaspe, null,cn.getConexion());
                    jasperView= new JasperViewer(print,false);
                    jasperView.setVisible(true);
```